# How install a custom theme to spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

It's possible to install a new theme in spacemacs?
How should I do this? I'm trying to install some theme from http://themegallery.robdor.com/

Answer (score 24):

1. Select your theme: http://themegallery.robdor.com/
2. Go to your dotfile: `SPC f e d`
3. Adding or edit the follow line adding our theme name(gruvbox in this example), make sure that is the first element of the list:

   ```lisp
   (defun dotspacemacs/init ()
     (setq-default
       ;; ... other configurations...
       dotspacemacs-themes '(gruvbox))
   ```
4. Reload your spacemacs: `SPC q R`

Comment: A hint, `SPC` or `Space` would not work unless you have chosen your permanent editing style as `Vim` in lieu of `Emacs`; then to solve the issue, for emacs user's, just use `M-m` (ie `Alt-m`).

Comment: `SPC f e R` worked for me to reload the configuration. But full restart was needed to actually apply a new theme.

Answer (score 11):

You need to first add themes mega-pack to your `.spacemacs`

- start `emacs`
- edit conf <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- udpate `dotspacemacs-configuration-layer` adding `themes-megapack`
- resync conf <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
- update `dotspacemacs/user-init`adding `dotspacemacs-themes '(jbeans)))`
  , replacing **jbeans** with your theme of choice
- restart conf <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Theme mega-pack broke my installation pretty hard. I'm running emacs 26.1 on Pop OS (Ubuntu derivative). All dark themes were permanently horked, and I had to delete .emacs.d and .spacemacs and start over.

Comment: I setup spacemacs this week and I'm able to just put the name of any theme from http://themegallery.robdor.com/ into the dotspacemacs-themes and when I restart spacemacs it provisions the theme for me (i.e. installs all package dependencies). I've not had to add/enable the themes mega-pack explicitly anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

**Installation and configuration.**

1. Open [the configuration dotfile](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8c0b8c3440a33df2c291088c47e75fd5e4fbbb61/core/templates/.spacemacs.template), `~/.spacemacs` , <kbd>M-m f e d</kbd>.
2. "Install" themes (two options).

   - Add the [`mega-pack` layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/themes-megapack) at the [layer section](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8c0b8c3440a33df2c291088c47e75fd5e4fbbb61/core/templates/.spacemacs.template#L32); or

     ```
     dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
     '(
       ...
       mega-pack
       ...
       )
     ```
   - Add a particular theme package at the [package section](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8c0b8c3440a33df2c291088c47e75fd5e4fbbb61/core/templates/.spacemacs.template#L57).

     ```
     dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(...
                                        ...
                                        sometheme-theme)
     ```
3. Set the themes to be loaded a the [theme section](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8c0b8c3440a33df2c291088c47e75fd5e4fbbb61/core/templates/.spacemacs.template#L129).

   ```
   dotspacemacs-themes '(sometheme-somevariant
                         sometheme-othervariant)
   ```
4. Resync configuration so themes are effectively installed, <kbd>M-m f e R</kbd>. Or restart, <kbd>M-m q R</kbd>.
5. Cycle themes by pressing <kbd>M-m T n</kbd>.

**Notes.**

- The [`mega-pack`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/layers/%2Bthemes/themes-megapack/packages.el) itself lists dozens of themes. If it is a personal (one user) setup, I recommend to simply install the specific theme packages that you are going to use.
- Each theme package may include several variants, like `solarized-theme` which includes `solarized-dark` and `solarized-light`.
- Two/three theme variants are enough.