# how to add custom theme to spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, themes

I'd like to add [this solarized theme](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized) to my spacemacs. How do I do it?

So far I added `(load-theme 'solarized t)` to my .spacemacs and I included it to my themes list. what I don't know is, where to put the downloaded directory from github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How install a custom theme to spacemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24958/how-install-a-custom-theme-to-spacemacs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to simple add *solarized-light (solarized-dark)* into *dotspacemacs-themes* list in *.spacemacs* file.

For example like this:

```
dotspacemacs-themes '(solarized-light
                      solarized-dark)
```

Spacemacs should figure it out on its own and no additional steps are necessary.