# How to add new themes to Spacemacs permanently?

Tags: spacemacs, themes

The accepted answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24959/16984) and other online resources suggest editing `dotspacemacs-themes`

```
dotspacemacs-themes '(solarized-light
                      solarized-dark)
```

I want to add two themes.

```
dotspacemacs-themes '(gruvbox
                      sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties)
```

On restart Spacemacs installs whichever theme is present on top. But after installation, if I change the order of themes, the new theme gets installed and previous theme for example "sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties" is lost.

I want to add themes such that when I do <kbd>Spc</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> (`helm-themes`) the theme appears in the list. Currently, only the top theme with other default themes appear in the list.

**Edit:**

I found [Themes Megapack layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/themes-megapack) in official repository, which I think is relevant to my issue. But I don't understand how to use it. I suggests

> To use this configuration layer, add it to your `~/.spacemacs`.

Where inside `~/.spacemacs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer from [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/7l0ja6/how_to_add_new_themes_to_spacemacs_permanently/).

## How to add new themes to the Spacemacs

This is done by modifying `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(gruvbox-theme
                                  color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow)
```

## How to use `themes-megapack`

Spacemacs comes with a pack of themes. To enable it edit `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`.

```
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(themes-megapack)
```

Few themes  in `themes-megapack` [have been removed from MELPA](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9952). To resolve the issue, configure `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages`.

```
dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '(firebelly-theme
                                 niflheim-theme
                                 pastels-on-dark-theme
                                 tronesque-theme
                                 zonokai-theme)
```

Comment: With adding the theme I wanted in dotspacemacs-additional-packages it work for me.